# Необходим контекст строк для правильного перевода

Tags: поддержка, локализация

Дорогие коллеги, вопрос обращён прежде всего к администрации.

На текущий момент правильный перевод многих фраз осложнён тем, что фраза в transifex не имеет контекста перевода. Например, переводя [«to cool down»](https://www.transifex.com/stack-exchange/stack-overflow-ru/translate/#ru/english/40263852?q=cool%20down), никто не знает, что эта фраза будет подставлена как `$reason$` в [`This account is $linkStart$temporarily suspended$linkEnd$$reason$. The suspension period ends $penaltyEndDate$.`](https://www.transifex.com/stack-exchange/stack-overflow-ru/translate/#ru/english/40540310?qt=%D0%91%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%B0%20%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BD%D1%87%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%81%D1%8F).

Поэтому переводчик переводит «to cool down» как «успокоиться», а не «, чтобы вы успокоились» или как-то ещё, более адекватно. Кроме того, переводчик не знает, где **ещё** используется та строка — может быть, единого адекватного перевода не существует?

Поэтому необходимо следующее: для *каждой* фразы в transifex нужно знать, где на сайте она появится. (Ещё хотелось бы знать, при каких условиях, если эти условия нетривиальны (например: репутация текущего пользователя между 5 и 20). Но это не критично.)

Кроме того, неплохо бы иметь и информацию в обратную сторону: для данного места в интерфейсе выяснить, какие строки из transifex могут там появляться.

Возможно, для этого нужна специальная версия сайта?

---

PS: Мне кажется сама практика составления предложений из кусков и перевода кусков по отдельности неверной. Структура предложений не каждого языка естественно ложится на структуру английского.

Answer (score 2):

К сожалению, сейчас нет какой-либо возможности автоматически добавлять контекст к строкам в связи с текущей архитектурой движка - база данных строк формируется на этапе компиляции (в этот момент создается хэш-таблица строк и их ключей).

Наши коллеги из сообщества Stack Overflow на японском предлагают объединиться в создании контекста. Идея сводится к добавлению меток к строкам, таким образом, чтобы было однозначно понятно, где именно она встречается. Например, если строка относится к учётной записи, её можно отметить меткой «profile». Сами метки можно переносить из одного проекта Transifex в другой. Таким обозом, вместе, мы сможем добавить контекст к большинству проблемных строк.

---

Создание инструмента, который сможет облегчить сообществу перевод сайта - одна из главных задач команды международных сообществ Stack Overflow. Если у вас есть какие-либо идеи по тому, как этот инструмент должен выглядеть, пожалуйста, опубликуйте их. Я, в свою очередь, вынесу их на обсуждение с ответственными разработчиками и затем опубликую их отзывы.

Comment: Есть какие-то изменения на этом фронте?